# Centos7 php-sodium dependency issues

Tags: php, centos7

Trying to install php8.1 on Centos7 following these instructions...https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2022/02/07/Install-PHP-8.1-on-Fedora-RHEL-CentOS-Alma-Rocky-or-other-clone

```
--> Processing Dependency: libsodium.so.23()(64bit) for package: php-sodium-8.1.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-sodium-8.1.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php81)
           Requires: libsodium.so.23()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-8.1.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php81)
           Requires: libgd.so.103()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcached-3.2.0-1.el7.remi.8.1.x86_64 (remi-php81)
           Requires: remi-libmemcached-awesome(x86-64)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Searching for libsodium to install as rpm
try to install other dependencies manually as rpms

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Notice: **CentOS 7** is now very old and close to its end of life in ~1 year.

For modern features, such as PHP 8.1, I recommend a modern version of the distribution (EL-8 or EL-9)

**libsodium** is available in the EPEL repository which is mandatory and seems to be missing or not enabled on your configuration.

As explained in the repository [FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#deps)